# Strange qualification criteria for a Thai resort

Tags: thailand, resorts

Whilst scouring the voucher sites I came across this in the fine print:

> Qualifying Criteria: Couples married or co-habituating for two or more
>   years, traveling together, singles officially registered with single
>   status are allowed, traveling alone, also qualify, must be homeowners,
>   your combined annual income must be superior to $70,000 equivalent
>   Disqualifying Criteria: Group travel is not permitted. A group is
>   defined as two or more families travelling during the same period to
>   the same resort area or property, two single people traveling together
>   is also classed as group travel and is not permitted, single when part
>   of a couple but travelling alone / without partner

My partner and I haven't yet got to the co-habitation stage, and her divorce was recently rejected on a technicality (despite being separated for many years), so I'm pretty sure that means we don't qualify.  Nevertheless, this has me curious...

What happens if someone purchases a voucher like this, makes the booking, and arrives at the resort only to discover they don't qualify? Do they check, if so when and how?

Comment: Stack Exchange is really designed for one single answerable question at a time. The problem with asking 4 distinct questions, as you have, is that if one person answers 1 and 2, and a different person answers 3 and 4, and both answers are correct and acceptable... which one do you accept? Please split your questions in to separate ones where possible.

Comment: What kind of voucher is this?  You say "the voucher sites" as if you expect people to know what those are...

Comment: I don't think there is an 'officially registered single status' in Thailand. I think it means that if you register as a single person then you will be allowed in (subject to the other criteria).

Comment: I think this is a workable and excellent question if it's edited to clarify the main question here, i.e., why and how the "criteria" affects someone travelling. As an aside, a lot of hotels in Asia want a "family" image of not allowing couples who aren't married, and that's what I think is going on here.

Comment: Thanks @CGCampbell.  Yes, I have had experience of other SE sites.  The problem I had with separating is the questions is that they are syntactically linked.  (1) and (2) refer to "who", (2) and (3) refer to "how", (1) and (4) refer to "what".  (4) is more about outcomes, which is interesting.  Like I said above, the whole thing is very mysterious and bizarre!  That being said, please help me if there's a better way of asking the question(s).

Comment: @nate-eldredge Sorry.  Voucher sites are where you purchase a voucher and then contact the company providing the product or service with the voucher to sort out the details.  The incentive being that the price is significantly reduced.  The risk being that the product or service may not be available on the exact date you want it.  I was surprised there wasn't a tag for it, to be honest!

Comment: Should I break this up into multiple questions?   Sounds a bit repetitive, too.

Comment: @tudor, I'd break out the "What is "officially registered...single status" in Thailand?". Then edit this question to just ask "What happens if someone purchases a voucher like this, makes the booking, and arrives at the resort only to discover they don't qualify? Do they check, if so when and how". Remove the "why do they do this", hopefully any answer will cover that but if it doesn't you can ask separately later. It might also help if you either name the resort, or give some general idea of location and type of resort. Also indicate if this is a timeshare, or just a vacation and what length.

Comment: This smells like timeshare rules to me. They don't want any "I would have to confirm with my spouse" excuses not to buy, and they don't want your friends with you giving moral support not to buy. You must bring whatever spouse you have, and nobody else, and you must have plenty of money. Whatever you think you're going to save on the hotel, run away. You might well find yourself buying a timeshare - these people are good. Everyone who goes there does so with their guard up, and yet enough get sold to keep the sellers in business.

Comment: @SpaceDog  Thanks!  That looks much better. :-D